# Showing a div using the droppable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, show, jquery-droppable

My code works as planned, except for one thing. When you click on the darkgray boxes the orange box appears with show();.

However, I want the purple box to appear when you drop the blue draggable div on the orange boxes. This doesn't seem to work.

My question to you is why doesn't this work in the drop function when it does work a few lines above, and how can I make this work?

I tried placing the purple div inside the orange one, but then it only shows once...
Any help much appreciated, let me know when you don't understand me.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTLUm/)** (problem is in the droppable function)

**jQuery**

```
$('.lightgray').hover(

function() {
    $(this).find('.darkgray').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.darkgray').fadeOut('fast');
});

$('.lightgray').bind("click", function(event) {

    $(this).find('.orange').show();
    $(this).unbind('hover');
});


$("#draggable_blue").draggable({

    revert: true
});


$('.orange').hover(

function() {
    $(this).find('.darkgray').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.darkgray').fadeOut('fast');
});


$(".orange").droppable({
    drop: function() {
         $(this).find('.purple').show();
    }
});
```

**Html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">

<div class="lightgray">

     <div class="darkgray">
     </div>

     <div class="orange">
     </div>
     <div class="purple">
     </div>

</div>

<div class="lightgray">

   <div class="darkgray">

    </div>
      <div class="orange">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="lightgray">

   <div class="darkgray">
    </div>
       <div class="orange">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="lightgray">
   <div class="darkgray">

    </div>
       <div class="orange">

    </div>
</div>
   <div class="orange">

    </div>
<div class="lightgray">

    <div class="darkgray">

    </div>
    <div class="orange">

    </div>
</div>
 <div class="lightgray">

   <div class="darkgray">
      </div>
        <div class="orange">

    </div>

</div>

<div class="lightgray">

    <div class="darkgray">

    </div>
<div class="orange">

    </div>
    </div>


<div class="lightgray">
    <div class="darkgray">

    </div>

 <div class="orange">

    </div>
</div>


       <div id="menu">
          <div id="draggable_blue">
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(this).parent().find('.purple').show();
```

here is the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/uTLUm/2/

`.find()` gets the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements. so with  `$(this).find()`, you were searchin inside `div.orange`, since your `div.purple` is outside. it won't be able to find `div.purple`.

i added the `parent()` so that it searched inside the current `div.lightgray` and hence find the purple div...

Comment: but if I placed the purple div inside the orange div, it only worked once. Can you explain me how that happens? Thanks

Comment: ok this is getting iinteressting..:)..only wokred once?? i am not getting you.... u meant the `purple div` shuld change to gray (watever) whn mouusehover too.. OR all the lightgray divs should turn purple.. i figured out.... only the first `lightgray div` have purple div... so it works for the first one only ... anyways let me know ur problem... 'll be helping you

Comment: You fixed my problem, i only tried some stuff out, your code works perfectly! :) Thank you

Comment: sure... have fun coding... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this update on your jsfiddle

```
........
$(".orange").droppable({
    drop: function() {
         $(this).hide();
        $(this).find('.purple').show();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTLUm/4/